# Azure search not returning correct result with . (dot) in search query

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

We have stored documents into azure search. One of the document is having below field value.

"Title": "statistics_query.compute_shader_invocations.secondary_inherited fails"

We have defined custom analyzer on it as per the recommendation from MS Azure Team, in order to resolve one of the issue we were facing due to _ (underscore).

```
{
  "name": "myindex",
  "fields": [
        {
            "name": "id",
            "type": "Edm.String",
            "searchable": true,
            "filterable": true,
            "retrievable": true,
            "sortable": false,
            "facetable": false,
            "key": true,
            "indexAnalyzer": null,
            "searchAnalyzer": null,
            "analyzer": null
        },
        {
            "name": "Title",
            "type": "Edm.String",
            "searchable": true,
            "filterable": true,
            "retrievable": true,
            "sortable": true,
            "facetable": true,
            "key": false,
            "indexAnalyzer": null,
            "searchAnalyzer": null,
            "analyzer": "remove_underscore"
        }
],
  "analyzers": [
    {
      "name": "remove_underscore",
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
      "charFilters": [
        "remove_underscore"
      ],
      "tokenizer": "standard_v2"
    }
  ],
  "charFilters": [
    {
      "name": "remove_underscore",
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.MappingCharFilter",
      "mappings": [
        "_=>-"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

However, when I search with below Filters on my azure search index (version # 2016-09-01 Preview), i didnt get any result.

$filter=search.ismatch('"compute_shader_invocations*"','Title', 'full', 'any')

$filter=search.ismatch('"compute_shader_invocations"','Title', 'full', 'any')

$filter=search.ismatch('"shader_invocations*"','Title', 'full', 'any')

However, if I include the text with (.) dot character, the same filter works.

$filter=search.ismatch('"query.compute_shader*"','Title', 'full', 'any')

Based on my tests, if the document is having a dot (.) character present right after or before the search term used in the filters, then the search doesnt return result.

So, below filters wont work as there is a (.) dot character present in the document, right before and after the search terms used in the query. In our case there is a dot character present before word "compute" and after word "invocations" in the Azure Search Document.

$filter=search.ismatch('"compute_shader_invocations*"','Title', 'full', 'any')

$filter=search.ismatch('"compute_shader"','Title', 'full', 'any')

$filter=search.ismatch('"shader_invocations*"','Title', 'full', 'any')

However below filters should work, as there is no dot character present before the word "query" or after the word "shadder" in the Azure search document

$filter=search.ismatch('"query.compute_shader*"','Title', 'full', 'any')
$filter=search.ismatch('"shader*"','Title', 'full', 'any')

This is driving me crazy. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

*tl;dr* Wildcard queries don't have custom analysis performed. Non wildcard queries should return results, so please double check

**Detailed answer**

So, the dot (.) actually doesn't have anything to do with the behavior you are observing. There are 2 classes of search queries you are issuing:

1. A wildcard query `*`
2. A non wildcard query (such as **"compute_shader"**)

In general, a non wildcard query you issue, will undergo the same analysis as defined by any custom analyzer in your index. In case of wildcard queries, no analysis is performed.

Now taking your document text as an example **"statistics_query.compute_shader_invocations.secondary_inherited fails"**, the custom analyzer you defined will break it down into tokens. (FYI: You can use the [Analyze API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/test-analyzer) to see the breakdown).

The following wildcard query succeeds

> $filter=search.ismatch('"shader*"','Title', 'full', 'any')

because, when you run the analysis on the source document, there are tokens like **"shader"**

The following wildcard queries don't succeed

> $filter=search.ismatch('"compute_shader_invocations*"','Title', 'full', 'any')
>   $filter=search.ismatch('"shader_invocations*"','Title', 'full', 'any')

because there are no tokens like **"computer_shader_invocations"** or **"shader_invocations"** when the source document is analyzed with your custom analyzer.

This one shouldn't succeed as well, but interestingly you say that it does:

> $filter=search.ismatch('"query.compute_shader*"','Title', 'full', 'any')

Let's focus now on queries without wildcards.

> $filter=search.ismatch('"compute_shader_invocations"','Title', 'full', 'any')
>   $filter=search.ismatch('"compute_shader"','Title', 'full', 'any')

These should technically get tokenized correctly using the custom analyzer and should have matching results.

**Could you please verify whether your queries in the last 3 highlighted instances were correct in your original question**? When I tried to create a sample index and issued a search request based on your configuration, those were the 3 anomalies I noticed. I would appreciate some clarification around those.

Also, in general the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture) around how full text search in Azure search works is a great place to get in-depth details about some of the things that I mentioned.

Comment: Also please note that you don’t need to use search.ismatch unless you plan to combine it with other filter expressions via “or”. You could just use the other Search API parameters directly (search, searchFields, and queryType).

Comment: Hi Arvind, yes I can confirm that all the queries in my original questions are correct.

Comment: Hi Arvind, yes I can confirm that all the queries in my original questions are correct. I can confirm that 
$filter=search.ismatch('"query.compute_shader*"','Title', 'full', 'any')
returns correct result.

And below filters wont work
$filter=search.ismatch('"compute_shader_invocations"','Title', 'full', 'any') $filter=search.ismatch('"compute_shader"','Title', 'full', 'any')

Comment: We must get this working with Filters only, we cant use Lucene Search as it doesnt have support for range searches.

Comment: Using the Analyze API it gave below token
Request
{
  "text": "statistics_query.compute_shader_invocations.secondary_inherited fails",
  "analyzer": "remove_underscore"
}
Response
[{"token":"statistics","startOffset":0,"endOffset":10,"position":0},{"token":"query.compute","startOffset":11,"endOffset":24,"position":1},{"token":"shader","startOffset":25,"endOffset":31,"position":2},{"token":"invocations.secondary","startOffset":32,"endOffset":53,"position":3},{"token":"inherited","startOffset":54,"endOffset":63,"position":4},{"token":"fails","startOffset":64,"endOffset":69,"position":5}]}

Comment: like I mentioned you can see that the (.) dot is part of token hence its not working i guess. But wondering why is partial match not working? so say for example if we have this token "query.compute" then search for query*, compute* , quer* , compu* should work, or is it that partial search is not possible?

Comment: So the thing with wildcard queries is that they don't go through the same custom analysis steps that you defined for the index. I am not 100% sure why we have discrepant results, but I can suggest a potential work around.

Could you try to add to your analyzer a custom step which says to replace the periods (.) with the hyphen? So that you get more granular tokens? That should theoretically help improve your search recall.

Comment: Can you please tell us how to do that? Let me know if I have to do it something like below

"mappings": [
        "_=>-",  ".=>-"
      ]

Also, how about matching the document with phrase "testing please ignore": with 
search.ismatch('"test*"','Title', 'full', 'any') , will test* match the token "testing"
????? At present its not :(

Highly appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Yes, you can use the mappings to replace period (.) with a hyphen. Again, like I said the lexical analysis does not apply to wildcard terms.
Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture#exceptions-to-lexical-analysis to get some more context

Comment: Thx Arvind. 

So, we will need to modify our “remove_undescore” charFilters to replace “.” (dot) with “-“ (hyphen) character, something like below.


"charFilters": [
    {
      "name": "remove_underscore",
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.MappingCharFilter",
      "mappings": [
        "_=>-", “.=>-“
      ]
    }
  ]


Do we need to reload the index again after modifying the analyzer?

Comment: Yes. I believe you need to add the analyzer to a new index and then upload your content to that index