# AZURE SEARCH, ismatch not filtering

Tags: azure, lucene, lucene.net, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I'm using Azure Search for perform some customs search in a database.

I got this one field that have this kind of structure:

"STUFF": "05-05-16-00|"

but I'm having trouble by creating the filter, because its possible that I'll not have all the numbers that builds this structure. It all depends that what the final user will type. So I need a wildcard to fill the blanks with the missing numbers, like this

"05-05-??-??"  -> the pipe is important, because this field can have more than 1 code inside.

Now I need to catch all the possible elements that STARTS WITH 05-05, like, for example: 05-05-11-01

I thought I suposed to use the search.ismatch() function, but it doesnt work.

here some code:

```
search.ismatch('05-05-??-??','STUFF');
```

And the results were:

```
"STUFF": "02-02-16-00|",
"STUFF": "02-02-14-00|",
```

this is driving me crazy, because I dont know why this results came back.

Maybe is important to know that Im performing a POST request to the Azure Search API with this code in 'filter'

Maybe i should to escape this especial characters like - and ? like this

```
search.ismatch('05\\-05\\-\\?\\?\\-\\?\\?','STUFF')
```

But the results were the same.

Can somebody please help me ?

**EDIT 1**

following this [Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48942334/azure-search-not-returning-correct-result-with-dot-in-search-query) I change some things and make the following search:

```
search.ismatch('\"05-00*\"','STUFF','simple', 'all')
```

And I starting the get some results, but now this is my results:

```
"STUFF": "06-05-02-00|", //WRONG
"STUFF": "05-02-05-01|", //RIGHT
"STUFF": "05-02-02-07|", //RIGHT
```

For some reason, it's returing the right structure but not the in the front of the text.

**EDIT 2**

I made some changes and change all the "-" for the keyword "OU" and I'm trying to follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893802/azure-search-find-matches-within-a-word-like-contains) to make sore like a "contains", but i perfoming a POST request with the following parameters

```
{
    "search": "*",
    "filter": "search.ismatch('/.*08010000OU/.*','STUFF', 'full', 'all')",
    "skip": "0",
    "count": true
}
```

Im trying to use a wildcard in the begining of the query search because I still missing some information.

Comment: stuff and 05-05* are being stored in the same field? can you provide a sample of your index definition?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Stuff is the field name, and de struture is the content inside of it, like this: "STUFF": "05-05-16-00|"

Comment: EDIT2: wildcards are not supported for the begging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you won't be able to solve this using the StandardAnalyzer. Try switching to WhitespaceAnalyzer for this particular field and it probably will work with `"05-05*"`

Comment: This is what I was trying to hide haha, I created a very small new index without the "-" and it works.

Comment: let me ask you one last thing:  could you please check the Edit 2,  valeu amigo (brasileiro né haha)